# How to check under Linux who is connected to my ad-hoc network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, gentoo

I made ad-hoc wireless network on my Gentoo workstation using NetworkManager. Is there any way to see what network adapters are connected to this network?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **nmap** to scan your network.

EX: nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24
this command list just machine that resopond to the ping.

Answer (score -1):

[netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) should be able to show this.

```
netstat -aenp | grep 'INSERT_IP_OF_ETH_ADAPTER_HERE'
```

For example:

```
[ 12:13 root@host ~ ]# netstat -aenp | grep '10.10.1.11'
tcp        0     52 10.10.1.11:22               198.74.40.169:46429         ESTABLISHED 0          34722586   29599/sshd: jon [pr
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.11:5109             10.10.1.34:62142            ESTABLISHED 505        23721631   28772/istatd
udp        0      0 10.10.1.11:123              0.0.0.0:*                               38         30885053   1611/ntpd
......
......
......
```

should show who is connected on a certain interface.  If you don't know the IP or interface to use, do `ifconfig -a` and see which is running your ad-hoc network and it should show the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I would rather want to know what device (mac address) is connected. Above shows connections made through my adapter.